# How to get VS_FIXEDFILEINFO.dwFileDateMS in C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, version, versioning

In C#, you can get file version information using `FileVersionInfo`. However this class seems to be incomplete. For example `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO`, which is the data stored with the file, contains `dwFileDateMS` and `dwFileDateLS`. Is there a different version info class in C# which can give me these fields, or some other technique?

Answer (score 2):

You can P/Invoke Win32 API [`Version Information Functions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and `VerQueryValue` the `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` of your interest. This is what .NET `FileVersionInfo` is supposedly doing but for some reason access to FileDate members is not provided (I suppose you will find them being zero and unused).

See [VS_FIXEDFILEINFO](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/168201-vs-fixedfileinfo/) and [Getting File Version Information](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/51b27133-4f56-4095-ae05-22c1fbbafea7) for code snippets.

Comment: It seems that `dwFileDateMS` and `dwFileDateLS` are always zero or otherwise ignored. [This document](https://bytepointer.com/resources/win32_res_format.htm) (section 4.1) appears to indicate that they are hard-codded to 0.